# Static allocation memory in C++

Tags: c++, memory

How can I calculate how much memory my C++ program takes ? 
( For example, if I have 1MB memory, how many integers I can use? )
Is in C++ a method that return the memory used by my program ?

Comment: You'll need to specify which implementation you use, i.e. OS and compiler (maybe even version). There is no standard way to do this.

Comment: Regardless of OS it's reasonable to expect that the executable file is mapped directly to memory. Since pages that aren't used need not occupy physical memory, only address range, the file size is directly the size of the address space used but only an upper bound on the physical memory that would be needed if nothing was swapped to disk. A memory block of size N bytes can hold at most N/sizeof(int) values of type int (it might be one less if it's not suitably aligned at the start).

Comment: I can't edit the earlier comment so just note, that for an executable mapped to memory it would be absurd to physically swap some part of it to disk, since the executable is already on disk. Instead with that mapping the executable serves as backing storage for the memory contents of the mapped area.